# Apache mod_substitute replace first occurence only

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, substitution, httpserver

I am quite new to Apache HTTP Server.

I am using the mod_substitute to transform urls like

```
http://www.example.com/appName/...
```

into

```
http://www.example.com**/root**/appName/...
```

My problem is handling urls like

```
http://www.example.com/appName/.../appName.js
```

Because my rewrite rule

```
SetOutputFilter INFLATE;SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute "s|/appName|/root/appName|i"
```

transform the above url in

```
http://www.example.com/root/appName/.../root/appName.js
```

and this will result in a 404 error.

Is there a way to substitute only the first occurrence with mod_substitute?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I'm late, but this may help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188264/want-to-substitute-only-first-occurence-with-sed

Comment: Your question helped me because I didn't have the SetOutputFilter directive. Now I have and my filter works.

Answer (score 0):

I am not explicitly familiar with mod_substitute, and the documentation doesn't mention what flavour of regex it uses, but you need to break this down to at least two cases: the URL starts with /appName/, or the URL starts with $SCHEME://www.example.com/appName hence something like:

```
Substitute "s/((?:['\"])\/appName\/|(?:www.example.com)\/appName\/|\/root/appName/i"
```

(The `(?:...)` prefix defines a pattern which is matched but not replaced).

NB I've not tested this. The syntax looks a lot like sed - I would strongly advise you experiment using sed before trying this out in your apache config.